# List of items has same index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following code is part of a dropdown with all the months of the year, where `Constants.MONTHS` is a list of all months.

```
var months = Constants.MONTHS;
for(var i = 0 ; i < months.length ; i++) {
  items.push(<li onClick={()=>this.chooseMonth(i)}><a href="#">{months[i]}</a></li>);
}
return items;
```

My issues is that whichever item in the dropdown list is clicked, the method `this.chooseMonth` is called with parameter `12`.

So it looks like `this.chooseMonth(i)` only gets the value of `i` from the last iteration.

How can I make every item in the dropdown call `this.chooseMonth` with a distinct index?

Comment: Either the dupe, or use ES2015 `let` instead.

Comment: This isn't valid syntax, if it was a properly formatted string wouldn't this work without worrying about closures?

Comment: It looks like React, not vanilla JS (would be good to mention in a post when React syntax is used.)

Comment: Oh alright, my bad